# How do I get the derivative of the function?

Tags: r, derivative, differentiation

How do I get the derivative of the following function?

```
g <- expression(x^2)
derivg <- D(g, 'x')
derivg
# 2 * x
g1 <- derivg(2)
# Error: could not find function "derivg"
```

I want to find the derivative at x = 2.

Comment: Did you check the `?D` help page? They have some pretty clear examples there.

Answer (score 11):

`derivg` is a call, not a function.  To evaluate it at `x = 2`, you can do

```
eval(derivg, list(x = 2))
[1] 4
```